# Implicit receiver

Tags: ruby, private, implicit

I am reading the book *Metaprogramming Ruby*, and trying to understand how private methods are used. It has this paragraph:

> first, you need an explicit receiver to call a method on an object that is not
>   yourself, and second, private methods can be called only with an implicit receiver.

Could anyone give me an example to illustrate this "you need an explicit receiver to call a method on an object that is not yourself"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the text you quote the "not yourself" means not in the same context (object) that the call was made.

In this example of a private method...

```
class Foo
  def bar
    baz
  end
  private
  def baz
    'hello'
  end
end
```

If you do

```
Foo.new.baz
```

You get an error, because `baz` was called with an explicit receiver (the part before the dot... `Foo.new`)

If you do

```
Foo.new.bar
=> "hello"
```

And that works because method `bar` called `baz` without a receiver.  It was able to call it without a receiver because `bar` (like `baz`) are both instance methods of the `Foo` object, so they have the same context (the same `self`). the `bar` method was calling `baz` on the same object that contains the `bar` method (i.e. "itself" or "yourself" if you think of yourself as sitting in the object as you write the object's methods).

Now rewrite the class as...

```
class Foo
  def bar
    self.baz
  end
  private
  def baz
    'hello'
  end
end
```

And now you see that `bar` no longer works, since you privded the receiver `self` (an explicit receiver) on the call to `baz` within the method `bar`.  Technically the exact same functionality (no receiver is the same as self as receiver) , but Ruby implements private methods by disallowing explicit receivers, even `self`.  So, as stated, private methods can't be called with an explicit receiver.

Every time you call a method on an object you are not calling that method on yourself (i.e. your context).

```
'george'.upcase
=> "GEORGE"
```

For `upcase` the explicit receiver is the part before the dot (the string object "george")

If you did

```
upcase
```

without specifying a receiver, it assumes you want to run `upcase` in your context (`self`) which in IRB is main:Object.  That's why you get

```
NameError: undefined lcoal variable or method `upcase' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically you are asking two questions.
explicit receiver/implicit receiver depends on how you call the method.
here's an example:

```
class MyClass
    def method1
        self.method2 # explicit reciever 'self'
        method2 # we call the same method but we don't pass a reciever -> implicit reciever
    end

    def method2
        puts "some text in here"
    end
end

mc_object = MyClass.new
mc_object.method1 # explicit reciever 'mc'
```

this code will print "some text in here" twice, one time witht the explicit call and one without it.

Now, private methods in ruby, are methods can only be called within the class itself, and when doing that you can only use implicit receiver.
In the next example we will add a new private method.

```
class MyClass
    def method1
        self.method2 # explicit reciever 'self'
        method2 # we call the same method but we don't pass a reciever => implicit reciever

        method3 # will work - implicit reciever
        self.method3 # will not work! - private method `method3' Error
    end

    def method2
        puts "some text in here"
    end

    private

    def method3
        puts "this text is private!"
    end
end
mc_object = MyClass.new
mc_object.method1 # explicit reciever 'mc'
mc_object.method3 # will not work! - private method `method3' Error
```

So you can see that trying to access a private method with a receiver (prefix 'self') will cause error, and also trying to access that method outside of the class definition will also cause a private method error.

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your first question:

> how private methods are used

Private methods are most commonly used to provide methods for a class that are only accessible to other methods in the same class. These methods are for the class' internal use only and are not callable from outside.